# Creating multiple intent with specific extra, always read the same extra

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I'm setting up an application with some notifications that are triggered by some Alarm. In order to set different notification, I take the current millis time as Id. However, when I'm passing it to intent through extra, it always receive the same value.

Here's my code, it'll be clearer :
In mainActivity we've :

```js
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var alarmManager: AlarmManager
    private lateinit var pendingIntent: PendingIntent

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        createNotificationChannel() //create a channel

    }
    
    //Set a notification that will be triggered in a given time in ms.
    //you can pass a title/description and Id in parameter
    private fun setNotification(timeMS: Long, title: String, description: String, id: Int){
        alarmManager = getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val intent = Intent(this, ReminderBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("title", title)
        intent.putExtra("description", description)
        intent.putExtra("id", id)

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeMS, pendingIntent)

    }

    //this button trigger a basics notification in 1 sec
    //here we use an id based on current time. We may use some parsed part of the corresponding deadline later.
    fun triggerNotification(view:View) {
        var id = System.currentTimeMillis().toInt()
        setNotification(System.currentTimeMillis()+1000, "foo", "ouafouaf", id)
    }
```

Then in ReminderBroadcastReceiver :

```js
class ReminderBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        var channelId = "remindersChannel"
        var title = intent!!.getStringExtra("title")
        var content = intent!!.getStringExtra("description")
        var notifId = intent!!.getIntExtra("id", 0)

        val intent2 = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent2!!.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK


        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

        val notifBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context!!, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentTitle(title + notifId.toString())
            .setContentText(content)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_REMINDER)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)

        val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
        notificationManager.notify(notifId, notifBuilder.build())
    }
}
```

My problem is that, if I click twice on the button at different time, the id received doesn't change. When I put `System.currentTimeMillis().toInt()` directly in notify's parameter, it works well.

Any Idea how to fix this?

Comment: The second parameter to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` needs to be different for each different notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter to PendingIntent.getBroadcast() needs to be different for each different notification.

(just use comment from CommonsWare to answer and close this thread)

Comment: Please ask original poster of the comment to post it as answer. Then you can mark it as accepted answer to close the question

Comment: I don’t want to waste his time, I’ll just mark this one as accepted asap